# How to add detailed specification in to user story?

Tags: user-story

I see there are many user stories that only contain
Story
Acceptance Criteria

Where to put the detailed requirements?
Is that unnecessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably unnecessary.

Historically, a story card is a placeholder for a conversation. Those conversations may lead to things being written down or perhaps split into other cards for other conversations later. What would be written would be enough for the team to satisfy their needs, which very well could be a few words for a description and some acceptance criteria.

Keep in mind that stories originated in Extreme Programming, which was one of the methodologies that led to Agile Software Development. One of the values of Agile Software Development is that agile software developers value "working software over comprehensive documentation". Create the documentation that is needed and that adds value when it is needed - no more, no less, no earlier.

Comment: Note that this approach only works with an extensive test suite. Otherwise, without documentation and tests, there’s no way of knowing if the observed behavior is correct.

Comment: @RikD Even with written requirements and documentation, there is a lot of ambiguity in human language. Unless you're using a formal specification language, having an extensive passing test suite (preferably automated) and user acceptance are the only ways to ensure the behavior is correct.